# Comparing User.Identity.Name.Substring with user name on Active directory will return misleading results

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have written the following method to store the username for log purposes:-

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
string ADusername = User.Identity.Name.Substring(User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\\") + 1);
repository.InsertOrUpdateTechnologyAssociation(ua, ADusername);
repository.Save();
//code hoes here
                }
```

The above will store the username for the administrator as “administrator” all lower case. While if I retrieve the user name from active directory as follow:-

```
public List<DomainContext> GetADUsers(string term=null)
        {
            List<DomainContext> results = new List<DomainContext>();
            using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "WIN-SPDEV"))
            using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
            {
                var searchResults = searcher.FindAll();



                foreach (Principal p in searchResults)
                {
                   if (term == null || p.SamAccountName.ToString().ToUpper().StartsWith(term.ToUpper()))
                   {
                    DomainContext dc = new DomainContext();
                    dc.DisplayName = p.DisplayName;
                    dc.UserPrincipalName = p.UserPrincipalName;
                    dc.Name = p.Name;
                    dc.SamAccountName = p.SamAccountName ;
                    dc.DistinguishedName =     p.DistinguishedName;

                    results.Add(dc);

                }
                }
            }
            return results;
        }
```

Then the Name & SamAccountName will be “Administrator” with capital A at the begging. So this caused problem inside my application as when I try to compare the login user with the username on active directory then the result was always false because Administrator  != administrator. So to solve this issue I wrote my comparison as follow by changing both values to be lower case then comparing them:-

```
bool isadminByuser =  tms.SecurityRoles.Where(a => a.Name == "Administrator").SingleOrDefault().SecurityRoleUsers.Any(a => a.UserName.ToLower() == user.ToLower());
```

so does such comparison cause problems in the future, or it is safe to change the suername to lower case.?
Or Administrator & administrator can represent two different users ??
Thanks

Comment: Try to use this overload when comparing strings. It makes it clear what comparison you are expecting, and lessens all the ToUpper/Lower noise. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c64xh8f9(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Active Directory usernames are not case sensitive. So basically `Administrator` and `administrator` represent the exact same account.

Comment: so my comparison should be ok?

Comment: I would favor culture invariant lowercase or uppercase comparisons in this case using the corresponding string.Equals overload.